# In C# which one contains boxing and unboxing strategy, array or arraylist?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, arraylist

Which of the following uses `Boxing` and `Unboxing` strategy?

- Array
- ArrayList

Comment: If you store a value type in an `ArrayList`, then it will be boxed, whereas an array of value type requires no boxing. That said, you should *never* use `ArrayList` now: `List<T>` is type-safe, and in fact will *not* box value types.

Comment: The "strategy" is to avoid boxing and unboxing. As @dlev said, just use `List<T>` everywhere, unless you have a *really* good reason not to.

Comment: @dlev: I fully agree, _unless_ T is `object`, where boxing might still occur. Of course, that should not be used unless absolutelly required.

Comment: @PMF What? dlev said `will not box value types`. `object` is the base of all _reference types_ .. so I don't get your comment.

Comment: I believe the point is that `List<object>` is a valid construction of `List<T>`, and using that will both allow value types to be inserted, and will in fact box them. But who cares? Obviously `List<object>` and `ArrayList` are roughly analogous; if you're using either, you should stop and consider if there's a better way.

Comment: @dlev Ah.. mis-interpreted what PMF meant. I apologise.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I could have been a little more precise in my original comment: `List<T>`, where `T` is a value type, will not box its elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array lists are not strongly type collection. It will store values of different datatypes or same datatype. 
So Array Lists use boxing unboxing technniques.

```
Boxing
```

Implicit conversion of a value type (int, char etc.) to a reference type (object), is known as Boxing.

```
Unboxing
```

Explicit conversion of same reference type (which may be created by boxing process); back to a value type is known as unboxing.

```
Exp-
```

// int (value type) is created on the Stack

```
int stackVar = 12;
```

// Boxing = int is created on the Heap (reference type)

```
object boxedVar = stackVar;
```

// Unboxing = boxed int is unboxed from the heap and assigned to an int stack variable

```
int unBoxed = (int)boxedVar;
```

Avoid Boxing an Unboxing

Comment: "assigned to a value type which is being allocated on the stack" - not necessarily!

Answer (score 0):

When value type is moved to a reference type it’s called as boxing. The vice-versa is termed as unboxing.

Below is sample code of boxing and unboxing where integer data type is converted in to object and then vice versa.

```
int i = 1;
object obj = i; // boxing
int j = (int) obj;  // unboxing
```

It is best to avoid using value types in situations where they must be boxed a high number of times, for example in non-generic collections classes such as System.Collections.ArrayList. You can avoid boxing of value types by using generic collections such as System.Collections.Generic.List. Boxing and unboxing are computationally expensive processes. When a value type is boxed, an entirely new object must be created. This can take up to 20 times longer than a simple reference assignment. When unboxing, the casting process can take four times as long as an assignment.

Related topics

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms173196.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

http://questpond.blog.com/2014/03/04/net-interview-questions-what-is-concept-of-boxing-and-unboxing

Answer (score 0):

When using ArrayList you have more overhead with boxing and unboxing, Array is strongly typed and more efficient than ArrayList.